# XAML Datatrigger on label doesn't update content

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to update the content of my label when I raise OnProperyChanged. I update the content and the background, the background is updated but not the text content.
I think there is a bug, maybe because I am in a listview ...

```
<GridViewColumn  Header="{Tr 'Scanning'}">
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
            <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="NotAnalyzed">
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="NotStarted">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Tr 'Not started'}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="InProgress">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Tr 'In progress'}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Cancel">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Tr 'Canceled'}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Finished">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Tr 'Done'}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Error">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Tr 'Error'}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

When the list is initialized, it works. The content and the background are corrects depending the value of StatutBrowsing.
When I raise the property change event on the property StatutBrowsing the background is well updated but the content is not.

I have tried using Label.Content instead of Content but the result is the same.

I can't understand why :/ Can you help me please ?

Comment: You sure you're not binding Content elsewhere? A local binding will overrule any style setter.

Comment: can you explain _Value="{Tr 'Error'}"_? Never seen such a thing in XAML :-)

Comment: If `{Tr ` is a custom markup extension, shouldn't it be prefixed by a namespace alias?
Maybe checking the Output window or XAML error window for details will narrow down reasons.

Comment: Tr is the tag which comes with https://github.com/codingseb/Localization to manage translations.

Comment: The solution is in the documentation : 
Tr and WPF Styles
The Trmarkup is usable in Styles. but if a Trigger is used the Tr markup only works if used in static mode : <Tr IsDynamic=False .... In dynamic mode the Trmarkup create in backend a Binding and do not allow to be modified by a Datatrigger. To do a localization in a same manner way, prefer to use a binding with a TrTextIdConverter in place of a trigger.
https://github.com/codingseb/Localization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code without all the `"{Tr...}"` works as expected.
It seems the root of your problem is there.
You can validate by changing all these usages to normal strings.
`{Tr 'Error'}` ==> `Error`

Here:

```
                         <DataTemplate>
                                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding StatutBrowsing}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                                    <Label.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding StatutBrowsing}"/> 
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="NotAnalyzed">
                                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="NotStarted">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Not started"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="InProgress">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="In progress"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Cancel">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Canceled"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Finished">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Done"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatutBrowsing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Error">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Error"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: The solution is in the documentation : 
Tr and WPF Styles
The Trmarkup is usable in Styles. but if a Trigger is used the Tr markup only works if used in static mode : <Tr IsDynamic=False .... In dynamic mode the Trmarkup create in backend a Binding and do not allow to be modified by a Datatrigger. To do a localization in a same manner way, prefer to use a binding with a TrTextIdConverter in place of a trigger.
https://github.com/codingseb/Localization